# weird json parse issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am facing a very weird jQuery behaviour related to json. Following is my code, in which I send a POST request to a servlet which sends a JSON response. I am able to retrieve the values for most of the requests but some for some requests, I get the following error while retrieving values from JSON:

```
parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
```

But when I check that JSON response (I am getting it from eclipse console) on this site: [enter link description here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

this site parses the JSON without giving any errors!! Goto site->copy any JSON in the textarea under 'Text' tab, then click on 'Viewer tab'. It will parse it correctly.

Following are 2-3 JSONs, for which jQuery reports error -

```
{"topics": [{ "categoryName":"Law Crime" , "score":"90%"}],"socialTags": [{ "originalValue":"Social inequality" , "importance":"1"},{ "originalValue":"Affirmative action" , "importance":"1"},{ "originalValue":"Discrimination" , "importance":"1"},{ "originalValue":"Education policy" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Politics" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Ethics" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Social philosophy" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Same-sex marriage in Canada" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Affirmative action in the United States" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Same-sex marriage in the United States" , "importance":"2"},{ "originalValue":"Law Crime" , "importance":"1"}],"entities": [{ "_type":"Facility" , "name":"Supreme
Court"},{ "_type":"Organization" , "name":"Supreme
Court"}]}
```

I have tried many times and every time for these JSONs I get the same error.

## I am creating these JSONs at the back end in servlet.

## Following is my code to retrieve values from JSON in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        //servlet url
        url: 'calaiscaller',
        // parameters 
        data: {content: summary},
        // expected data-type of response
        dataType: 'json',
        // to execute when got the json result
        success: function(jsonResponse){            
            // clear the old topic data 
            $('#topics').empty();
            $('#topics').append("<p class='text-left label label-info'>Topics:</p>");   
            // add new topic data
            $.each(jsonResponse.topics, function(){
                var topicData="<p><span class='text-left'>" + this.categoryName + "</span><span class='pull-right'>" + this.score + "</span></p>";
                $('#topics').append(topicData);
            });

            // clear new social-tag data
            $('#social-tags').empty();
            $('#social-tags').append("<p class='text-left label label-info'>Social Tags:</p>");
            // add new social-tag data
            $.each(jsonResponse.socialTags, function(){
                var socialTagData="<p><span class='text-left'>" + this.originalValue + "</span><span class='pull-right'>" + this.importance + "</span></p>";
                $('#social-tags').append(socialTagData);
            });

            // clear new entities data
            $('#entities').empty();
            $('#entities').append("<p class='text-left label label-info'>Entities:</p>");
            // add new entities data
            $.each(jsonResponse.entities, function(){
                var entitiesData="<p><span class='text-left'>" + this._type + "</span><span class='pull-right'>" + this.name + "</span></p>";
                $('#entities').append(entitiesData);
            });

            //alert('success');
            // write the success status
            $('#statusField'+uniqueId).addClass('alert alert-success pull-left');
            $('#statusField'+uniqueId).append('Success!');
        },

        // to execute when error
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert("error");
            //alert(textStatus);
            //alert(errorThrown);
            // print the error
            // write the error message
            $('#statusField'+uniqueId).addClass('alert alert-error pull-left');
            $('#statusField'+uniqueId).append('Error: '+textStatus+', '+errorThrown);
        },

        // always executed at last whether success or error
        complete: function(){
            // bring back submit button to its original state
            $('.showinfo').button('reset');
            // hide the progress bar
            $('#progress').hide();
            // fade in the results
            $('#resultbox').fadeIn('slow', function(){

            });
        }
    });
```

Help!

Comment: This error normally appears in valid-**looking** JSON when an invisible unicode character (no-space or an unusual whitespace or something similar) has somehow magically found it's way into the response.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ gives better hints what's wrong with JSON.

Comment: It's invalid json on line `57`

Comment: @Christoph - I rolled back your edit because for some reason you removed the error from the original JSON.

Comment: i ran it trough jsonlint becasue i had the same thought but it says it's valid as well

Comment: Using jsonlint shows that there's a `\n` in the word `Supreme Court`

Comment: @SnakeEyes - Why would you beautify the JSON when the point of the question was to find out what was wrong with the original?

Comment: i wonder if you instead of ussing and array [] just make it strict JSON {} if that fixes it

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ says: Parse error on line 57:
...            "name": "SupremeCourt"    
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: Timothy Groote removed the error with his edit, I just put the result into jsonlint and everything was fine so i thought it would be okay to insert the formated json here. Apparently it's like Paul said. The linebreak character invalidated your json.

Comment: now it does before when it was beuatfied it didn't

Comment: @Christoph: jsonlint report the error, and it is bec of newline. Other websites were not reporting the error!!

Comment: Actually you can see the error in your json with naked eye - the codeline in your question wraps twice while it should not break at all.

Comment: Thanks Cristoph!!! after doing replaceAll([\n\r], " "); it is solved!!

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ was not reporting any error..!! not even http://json.parser.online.fr/ .... will always trust jsonlint now!

Comment: You are welcome;) Btw, http://json.parser.online.fr/ tells me something about an error, but does not show where. Just accept nnnnn's answer to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about json.parser.online.fr! It reports error. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ doesnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original JSON was invalid because of carriage returns in the values. In the first JSON string:

```
"name": "U.S.
Supreme Court"
```

In the second string:

```
"name": "Supreme
Court"
```

If you want a carriage return use `\n`, as in `"Supreme\nCourt"` - but I suspect you don't actually want that, you just want a space.

If you have a particular JSON string that is giving an error you can validate it at http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: ah that's right control character refers to returns .. should have know that just wasn't hitting the brain

Comment: aaha! After doing replaceAll([\n\r], " "); it is solved! Thanks!